# Apache responding with Request Entity Too Large

Tags: apache-2.2

My apache server sends a "Request Entity too Large" error, when I am trying to upload a file. This happens when the actual "post body" is sent by the client after about 10 seconds of sending the "request header". Is there any way to disable this on Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There is a Apache setting for this:

RequestReadTimeout

More can be found at:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html

Comment: The document say that it returns 408 REQUEST TIME OUT, not 413 Request Entity Too Large.

Answer (score 10):

There's a method using mod_security, assuming you don't mind making it much larger:

`You can also limit the size of the HTTP request body data. This is very handy for disabling large data in HTTP POST requests.`

`SecRequestBodyLimit 10485760`

This is probably worth a read about any consequences of such a change: [Mod Security HOWTO](http://linuxgazette.net/143/pfeiffer.html)

Comment: Was looking for a reason why for hours and completely forgotten about enabled `mod_security` and its directives! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP on the server to upload the file, you might want to look in your apache configs for something that looks like `"LimitRequestBody"`  or other restrictions on the size of the data allowed for upload.  `post_max_size` is another thing to look for in php.ini, along with `upload_max_filesize`

Answer (score 0):

It's what worked for me:

in modsecurity.conf file

On my Ubuntu 14.04 the config file is here but this really depends on the system:/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf

change this two commands to this values:

SecRequestBodyLimit 13107200

SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 13107200